# log4j smtp appender overriding gives unexpected behavior?

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I have overridden log4j smtp appender for some purpose. The problem is if i keep `<param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>`  Then it would send mails properly. But if i keep `<param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>` Then no mails are sent. What is the problem? Please find my code.

```
public class MyAppender extends SMTPAppender{
  @Override
    protected void sendBuffer() {
          //Some code to format email body

    }

}
```

### log4j.xml

```
<!-- Appenders -->



<appender name="mail" class="com.service.MyAppender">
    <param name="BufferSize" value="2"/>
    <param name="BufferedIO" value="true"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>
    <param name="SMTPHost" value="myhost"/>
    <param name="From" value="abc@co.com"/>
    <param name="To" value="def@ld.com"/>
    <param name="Subject" value="Testing Testing"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
               value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{2}:%L - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>


<appender name="ASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <param name="BufferSize" value="500"/>
    <appender-ref ref="mail"/>
</appender>


<root>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
</root>
```

I looked into `SMTPAppender` source code and i believe below lines are the problem.

```
if(evaluator.isTriggeringEvent(event)) {
      sendBuffer();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [log4j documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a2.9), all log events with value *lower* than Treshold will be filtered out (i.e. not sent).

It's possible that changing Treshold to more restrictive filters out **all** messages that are logged in your case.
Make sure that you actually have events with log level ERROR (or higher - FATAL).